# Accessing an FTP directory listing with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I need to download data from the Bureau of Labor Statistics' public FTP server for analysis. I'm attempting to use PHP to retrieve a listing, but I'm not sure how to do it with a public FTP server - using no ftp_login results in "false" being returned, and attempting to login as anonymous hangs the script.

My code:

```
<?php
// set up basic connection
$ftp = ftp_connect("ftp.bls.gov");
       ftp_login($ftp, "anonymous", "");
             ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
var_dump(ftp_rawlist($ftp, "/pub/time.series/la/"));
?>
```

Comment: Your code works for me exactly as it is.

Comment: Where do you run that code? I had no problems to get it to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your script works for me ([see output](http://codepad.org/oPiuabFH)), I get a nice directory listing. Please contact the system administration of the server your PHP script is running and ask for support. It looks like that this is a network configuration issue to me.

Additionally always check function return values for errors before you continue:

```
// connect
$ftp = ftp_connect("ftp.bls.gov");
if (!$ftp) die('could not connect.');

// login
$r = ftp_login($ftp, "anonymous", "");
if (!$r) die('could not login.');

// enter passive mode
$r = ftp_pasv($ftp, true);
if (!$r) die('could not enable passive mode.');

// get listing
$r = ftp_rawlist($ftp, "/pub/time.series/la/");
var_dump($r);
```

---

> #### What is Anonymous FTP?
>
> Anonymous FTP is a means by which archive sites allow general access
>      to their archives of information.  These sites create a special
>      account called "anonymous".  User "anonymous" has limited access
>      rights to the archive host, as well as some operating restrictions.
>      In fact, the only operations allowed are logging in using FTP,
>      listing the contents of a limited set of directories, and retrieving
>      files.  Some sites limit the contents of a directory listing an
>      anonymous user can see as well.  Note that "anonymous" users are not
>      usually allowed to transfer files TO the archive site, but can only
>      retrieve files from such a site.
>
> Traditionally, this special anonymous user account accepts any string
>      as a password, although it is common to use either the password
>      "guest" or one's electronic mail (e-mail) address.  Some archive
>      sites now explicitly ask for the user's e-mail address and will not
>      allow login with the "guest" password.  Providing an e-mail address
>      is a courtesy that allows archive site operators to get some idea of
>      who is using their services.

Excerpt from: [How to Use Anonymous FTP (RFC 1635)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1635.txt)

Comment: Originally I tried with a blank password field, this seems to be why. I replaced it with "guest". Thanks.

Comment: Works with a blank password for me, too. I first thought that a blank password might be an issue, but it's not for that server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Php code. Hope it'll be helpful:

```
<?php
$connect = ftp_connect("ftp.hostname.com"); 
$result = ftp_login($connect, "username", "password");
$a = ftp_nlist($connect, "code22");

foreach($a as $value){
    echo $value,"<BR>";
}
?>
```