# How to connect to an ftp server from a web site?

Tags: php, html, web, ftp

I would need to connect to my FTP server from my website. I'll explain. What I need is for my website to show a login form with username and password to the FTP server and when you log in it will automatically show the content of it. Something similar to what browsers do when you enter ftp:\name servers that ask you for username and password and show the contents of the server.

Comment: Hi! Thank you! I would use PHP

Comment: Done! Thank you so much!!

Comment: The question is too broad. Ask a more specific question.

Comment: Documentation of FTP functions in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php

Comment: Yes, indeed. The question is way too broad. Start for example here: [Accessing an FTP directory listing with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6747065/850848) - And if you have additional, *more specific* questions, post them separately.

Answer (score -3):

There would be a lot of work involved to do this from scratch, your best bet would be to use a package like https://github.com/Nicolab/php-ftp-client